# Postgresql sometimes gets high IO issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, write-ahead-logging, checkpoint

I have a [Sanic](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/) app  using [asyncpg](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg) (0.13) to work with postgresql (9.5). My server now facing a problem which sometimes postgresql seems to be freezed and my app can't even read from db and it seems like a downtime for the app, this issue happens frequently within around 30mins.

**UPDATE1: All my graph is in UTC+7, log is in UTC time.**

This is how our CPU looks like when the high IO happens:

[image]

The CPU iowait gets high at the points.

When I set a cronjob to capture iotop, I see the `wal writer process` is taking a lot of io and also many INSERT processes:

```
16:30:54 29266 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 5077.89 K/s  0.00 % 31.95 % postgres: wal writer process
16:30:54 29307 be/4 postgres   58.96 K/s  117.92 K/s  0.00 % 12.55 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43014) INSERT
16:30:54 29327 be/4 postgres   14.74 K/s  154.77 K/s  0.00 %  8.70 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43648) INSERT
16:30:54 29359 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s  176.88 K/s  0.00 %  2.84 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45220) idle
16:30:54 29298 be/4 postgres  243.21 K/s 1562.43 K/s  0.00 %  0.82 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(42868) INSERT
16:30:54 29345 be/4 postgres   58.96 K/s  154.77 K/s  0.00 %  0.72 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45134) INSERT
16:30:54 29354 be/4 postgres   73.70 K/s  397.98 K/s  0.00 %  0.51 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45178) INSERT
16:30:54 29318 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s  316.91 K/s  0.00 %  0.10 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43498) INSERT
16:30:54   775 be/3 root        0.00 K/s   18.42 K/s  0.00 %  0.09 % [jbd2/sda3-8]
16:30:54 29344 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s  302.17 K/s  0.00 %  0.08 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45118) INSERT
16:30:54 29367 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s  117.92 K/s  0.00 %  0.07 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45342) INSERT
16:30:54 29350 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s   95.81 K/s  0.00 %  0.06 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45154) INSERT
16:30:54 29348 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s  265.32 K/s  0.00 %  0.05 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45148) INSERT
16:30:54 29352 be/4 postgres    7.37 K/s  331.65 K/s  0.00 %  0.04 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45164) INSERT
16:30:54 29355 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s  213.73 K/s  0.00 %  0.04 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45183) INSERT
....
16:30:55 29341 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 14183.25 K/s  0.00 % 64.19 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45084) SELECT
16:30:55 29319 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s  966.20 K/s  0.00 %  9.50 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43506) idle
16:30:55 29298 be/4 postgres   66.38 K/s    7.38 K/s  0.00 %  0.21 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(42868) INSERT
16:30:55 29313 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 1386.61 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43276) idle
16:30:56 29378 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 12833.52 K/s  0.00 % 45.54 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45522) idle
16:30:56 29266 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 8291.20 K/s  0.00 % 39.46 % postgres: wal writer process
16:30:56 29354 be/4 postgres  138.31 K/s   14.56 K/s  0.00 % 25.38 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45178) INSERT
16:30:56 29307 be/4 postgres   21.84 K/s    0.00 K/s  0.00 %  2.76 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43014) INSERT
16:30:56 29345 be/4 postgres   36.40 K/s    7.28 K/s  0.00 %  0.33 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45134) INSERT
16:30:56 29298 be/4 postgres   21.84 K/s   14.56 K/s  0.00 %  0.12 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(42868) INSERT
16:30:56 29308 be/4 postgres    7.28 K/s   14.56 K/s  0.00 %  0.08 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43016) INSERT
16:30:57 29378 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 7622.73 K/s  0.00 % 41.67 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45522) idle
16:30:57 29266 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 7475.71 K/s  0.00 % 39.79 % postgres: wal writer process
16:30:57 29371 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 7438.96 K/s  0.00 % 11.22 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45422) INSERT
16:30:57 29354 be/4 postgres  246.25 K/s  117.61 K/s  0.00 %  2.71 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45178) INSERT
16:30:57 29308 be/4 postgres   36.75 K/s   29.40 K/s  0.00 %  1.23 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43016) INSERT
16:30:57 29345 be/4 postgres   14.70 K/s   22.05 K/s  0.00 %  0.68 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45134) INSERT
16:30:57 29288 be/4 postgres   22.05 K/s    7.35 K/s  0.00 %  0.08 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(42840) INSERT
16:30:58 29371 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 3445.89 K/s  0.00 % 33.64 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45422) idle
16:30:58 29345 be/4 postgres   29.71 K/s   22.28 K/s  0.00 % 27.62 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45134) INSERT
16:30:58 29266 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 4262.81 K/s  0.00 % 27.22 % postgres: wal writer process
16:30:59 29335 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 11094.36 K/s  0.00 % 56.84 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(44674) idle
16:30:59 29266 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 4193.67 K/s  0.00 % 14.18 % postgres: wal writer process
16:30:59 29314 be/4 postgres  177.51 K/s    0.00 K/s  0.00 %  0.80 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43390) INSERT
16:30:59 29353 be/4 postgres  147.92 K/s   44.38 K/s  0.00 %  0.47 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45174) INSERT
16:30:59 29355 be/4 postgres   22.19 K/s    0.00 K/s  0.00 %  0.38 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45183) INSERT
16:30:59 29352 be/4 postgres   59.17 K/s   22.19 K/s  0.00 %  0.14 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45164) INSERT
16:30:59   775 be/3 root        0.00 K/s   22.19 K/s  0.00 %  0.04 % [jbd2/sda3-8]
16:31:00 29266 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s 6199.25 K/s  0.00 % 64.44 % postgres: wal writer process
16:31:00 29294 be/4 postgres  189.18 K/s 3383.39 K/s  0.00 %  1.06 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(42864) INSERT
16:31:00 29316 be/4 postgres   69.12 K/s  552.98 K/s  0.00 %  0.42 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43478) INSERT
16:31:00 29307 be/4 postgres    7.28 K/s  734.89 K/s  0.00 %  0.03 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43014) INSERT
16:31:00 29324 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s  254.66 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43574) INSERT
16:31:00 29354 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s  312.87 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45178) INSERT
16:31:00 29373 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s  254.66 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(45454) INSERT
16:31:00 29284 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s  371.08 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(42806) INSERT
16:31:00 29318 be/4 postgres    0.00 K/s  232.84 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % postgres: db db 127.0.0.1(43498) INSERT
...(skipped as many times repeat like above)
```

Enable the slow query logs, I see many INSERT queries are being executed with  duration is very high (this is just two sample log entries, I see many in slow query log):

```
2018-01-15 18:33:02 UTC [2335-9] db@db LOG:  duration: 35436.589 ms  execute __asyncpg_stmt_53__: INSERT INTO my_table (site_id, source, language, query, data) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
2018-01-15 18:33:02 UTC [2335-10] db@db DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '121', $2 = 'source1', $3 = 'en', $4 = 'query1', $5 = '["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", "data6", "data7", "data8", "data9"]'
2018-01-15 18:33:02 UTC [3564-1] db@db LOG:  duration: 35109.508 ms  execute __asyncpg_stmt_10__: INSERT INTO my_table (site_id, source, language, query, data) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
2018-01-15 18:33:02 UTC [3564-2] db@db DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '16', $2 = 'source1', $3 = 'en', $4 = 'query2', $5 = '["fdata1", "fdata2", "fdata3"]'
```

I've tried with some changes to wal settings but no luck.

My server configuration:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- CPU: 16 Cores
- RAM: 48 GB
- SSD: 2 x 1TB (RAID)

Current configuration of postgresql.conf:

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main'
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf'
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_ident.conf'
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/9.5-main.pid'
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
max_connections = 600
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'
ssl = true
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'
shared_buffers = 12GB # min 128kB
work_mem = 1024MB # min 64kB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix
max_wal_size = 2GB
min_wal_size = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7 # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
effective_cache_size = 36GB
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log' # log file name pattern,
log_min_duration_statement = 800
log_checkpoints = on
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p-%l] %q%u@%d '
log_statement = 'none'
log_timezone = 'localtime'
stats_temp_directory = '/var/run/postgresql/9.5-main.pg_stat_tmp'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'localtime'
lc_messages = 'en_US'
lc_monetary = 'en_US'
lc_numeric = 'en_US'
lc_time = 'en_US'
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

**UPDATE1: update graph of Disk IO and checkpoint log at latest time. Timezone of graph is UTC+7, in logs is UTC**

Disk IO

[image]

Checkpoint logs:

```
2018-01-16 00:02:31 UTC [2327-140] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 14969 buffers (1.0%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 45 recycled; write=209.887 s, sync=
0.088 s, total=210.012 s; sync files=23, longest=0.026 s, average=0.003 s; distance=109576 kB, estimate=680298 kB
2018-01-16 00:04:01 UTC [2327-141] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 00:07:31 UTC [2327-142] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 14170 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 7 recycled; write=209.764 s, sync=0
.826 s, total=210.603 s; sync files=23, longest=0.810 s, average=0.035 s; distance=102605 kB, estimate=622528 kB
2018-01-16 00:09:01 UTC [2327-143] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 00:12:31 UTC [2327-144] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 12909 buffers (0.8%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 6 recycled; write=209.073 s, sync=0
.035 s, total=209.117 s; sync files=24, longest=0.014 s, average=0.001 s; distance=92767 kB, estimate=569552 kB
2018-01-16 00:14:01 UTC [2327-145] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 00:17:31 UTC [2327-146] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 12436 buffers (0.8%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 6 recycled; write=209.871 s, sync=0
.268 s, total=210.149 s; sync files=23, longest=0.221 s, average=0.011 s; distance=89671 kB, estimate=521564 kB
2018-01-16 00:19:01 UTC [2327-147] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 00:22:31 UTC [2327-148] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 13526 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 5 recycled; write=209.679 s, sync=0
.250 s, total=209.940 s; sync files=22, longest=0.230 s, average=0.011 s; distance=97622 kB, estimate=479170 kB
2018-01-16 00:23:31 UTC [2327-149] LOG:  checkpoint starting: xlog
2018-01-16 00:27:01 UTC [2327-150] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 37681 buffers (2.4%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 6 recycled; write=209.768 s, sync=0
.242 s, total=210.162 s; sync files=25, longest=0.212 s, average=0.009 s; distance=826683 kB, estimate=826683 kB
2018-01-16 00:28:31 UTC [2327-151] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 00:32:01 UTC [2327-152] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 14171 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 51 recycled; write=209.688 s, sync=0.025 s, total=209.759 s; sync files=25, longest=0.009 s, average=0.001 s; distance=127439 kB, estimate=756758 kB
2018-01-16 00:33:31 UTC [2327-153] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 00:37:01 UTC [2327-154] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 14017 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 7 recycled; write=209.888 s, sync=0.246 s, total=210.144 s; sync files=23, longest=0.209 s, average=0.010 s; distance=101314 kB, estimate=691214 kB
2018-01-16 00:38:31 UTC [2327-155] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 00:42:01 UTC [2327-156] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 13367 buffers (0.8%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 7 recycled; write=209.650 s, sync=0.331 s, total=209.990 s; sync files=23, longest=0.313 s, average=0.014 s; distance=96501 kB, estimate=631743 kB
2018-01-16 00:43:31 UTC [2327-157] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 00:47:01 UTC [2327-158] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 13254 buffers (0.8%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 5 recycled; write=209.678 s, sync=0.134 s, total=209.821 s; sync files=24, longest=0.091 s, average=0.005 s; distance=96178 kB, estimate=578186 kB
2018-01-16 00:48:31 UTC [2327-159] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 00:52:01 UTC [2327-160] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 14697 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 6 recycled; write=209.691 s, sync=0.019 s, total=209.719 s; sync files=23, longest=0.004 s, average=0.000 s; distance=105870 kB, estimate=530955 kB
2018-01-16 00:53:31 UTC [2327-161] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 00:56:34 UTC [2327-162] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 13252 buffers (0.8%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 7 recycled; write=181.523 s, sync=1.289 s, total=183.484 s; sync files=23, longest=1.114 s, average=0.056 s; distance=96174 kB, estimate=487476 kB
2018-01-16 00:58:31 UTC [2327-163] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 01:02:01 UTC [2327-164] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 39830 buffers (2.5%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 6 recycled; write=209.476 s, sync=0
2018-01-16 01:03:31 UTC [2327-165] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 01:07:01 UTC [2327-166] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 13818 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 46 recycled; write=209.792 s, sync=0.206 s, total=210.033 s; sync files=25, longest=0.117 s, average=0.008 s; distance=101866 kB, estimate=697495 kB

2018-01-16 01:08:31 UTC [2327-167] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 01:12:01 UTC [2327-168] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 13099 buffers (0.8%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 7 recycled; write=209.579 s, sync=0.023 s, total=209.610
s; sync files=24, longest=0.007 s, average=0.000 s; distance=94894 kB, estimate=637235 kB
2018-01-16 01:13:31 UTC [2327-169] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 01:17:01 UTC [2327-170] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 12166 buffers (0.8%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 5 recycled; write=209.925 s, sync=0.183 s, total=210.116
s; sync files=23, longest=0.093 s, average=0.007 s; distance=87555 kB, estimate=582267 kB
2018-01-16 01:18:31 UTC [2327-171] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 01:22:01 UTC [2327-172] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 13424 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 6 recycled; write=209.778 s, sync=0.318 s, total=210.105
s; sync files=23, longest=0.271 s, average=0.013 s; distance=97418 kB, estimate=533782 kB
2018-01-16 01:23:31 UTC [2327-173] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 01:27:01 UTC [2327-174] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 14004 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 6 recycled; write=209.586 s, sync=0.019 s, total=209.614
s; sync files=23, longest=0.003 s, average=0.000 s; distance=100902 kB, estimate=490494 kB
2018-01-16 01:28:31 UTC [2327-175] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 01:31:55 UTC [2327-176] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 13732 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 6 recycled; write=201.798 s, sync=1.494 s, total=204.044
s; sync files=23, longest=0.928 s, average=0.064 s; distance=99437 kB, estimate=451388 kB
2018-01-16 01:33:31 UTC [2327-177] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 01:37:01 UTC [2327-178] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 38289 buffers (2.4%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 6 recycled; write=209.782 s, sync=0.746 s, total=210.560
s; sync files=25, longest=0.705 s, average=0.029 s; distance=777938 kB, estimate=777938 kB
2018-01-16 01:38:31 UTC [2327-179] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 01:42:01 UTC [2327-180] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 13577 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 47 recycled; write=209.081 s, sync=0.127 s, total=209.243
 s; sync files=24, longest=0.081 s, average=0.005 s; distance=99142 kB, estimate=710058 kB
2018-01-16 01:43:31 UTC [2327-181] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 01:47:01 UTC [2327-182] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 14056 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 6 recycled; write=209.812 s, sync=0.532 s, total=210.354
s; sync files=23, longest=0.493 s, average=0.023 s; distance=102243 kB, estimate=649277 kB
2018-01-16 01:48:31 UTC [2327-183] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2018-01-16 01:52:01 UTC [2327-184] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 13446 buffers (0.9%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 7 recycled; write=209.405 s, sync=0.019 s, total=209.435
s; sync files=23, longest=0.006 s, average=0.000 s; distance=97228 kB, estimate=594072 kB
2018-01-16 01:53:31 UTC [2327-185] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
```

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Thanks,

**UPDATE2: update log of checkpoint since first spike event**

Comment: Try with a smaller `shared_buffers` (eg. 4GB), and a higher `checkpoint_completion_target` (eg. 0.9). There is likely some [bgwriter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-resource.html) tuning that's possible too. Some good info at [Basics of Tuning Checkpoints](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/basics-of-tuning-checkpoints/)

Comment: @bma I already tried to reduce `shared_buffers` and increase `checkpoint_completion_target` but the issue is still there. I read some articles and tried their suggestions too but still no luck, any other ideas?

Comment: One problem is I dont' understand why this issue happens periodically like a cron...

Comment: Looking at the checkpoint logs, could you increase the `max_wal_size` to `10 GB` or more, depending on the amount of data when `crontab`.

Comment: @LuanHuynh tried that too but the spike still remains..

Comment: Just to confirm, you did restart Postgres after changing `shared_buffers`?

Comment: @bma sure I did